# Polynomial calculation in SymPy

Tags: python, symbolic-math, sympy

Thie programs is written in Sympy 1.9 and it should find a polynomial `g` of degree `dim`  for a given polynomial `f` such that `f o g = g o f` as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4339046/11206), where I already posted program written in Maxima.
This is my first program in SymPy so I am interested in your feedback on this program except on the algorithm itself.

```
from sympy import symbols, pprint, expand, Poly, IndexedBase, Idx,Eq,solve
from sympy.abc import x,f,g,i
fg,gf,d=symbols('fg gf d')

f=x**3+3*x  # a polynomial g exists
#f=x**3+4*x # a polynomial g does not exist
dim=5

a=IndexedBase('a')
i=Idx('i',dim)

# create a polynomial of degree dim 
# with unknown coefficients,
# but the coefficient of the highest power is 1
# an the lowest power is 1
g=a[0]+x**dim
for i in range(1,dim):
    g+=x**i*a[i]

# calculate fg = f o g 
# and gf = g o f
fg=f
gf=g
fg=expand(f.subs(x,g))
gf=expand(g.subs(x,f))

# calculate the difference d=(f o g) - (g o f)
# and check how to choose the coefficients of g
# such that it will become 0

difference=(fg-gf).as_poly(x)
candidates=solve(difference.all_coeffs()[:dim],[a[i] for i in range(dim)])
replacements=[(a[i],candidates[0][i]) for i in range(dim)]

if (difference.subs(replacements)==0):
    pprint(g.subs(replacements))
else:
    print("no solution exists")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Turning into a Function

I would advise turning your program into a function. This allows people to use your function in other Python scripts. That is:

```
def poly_commute(f, dim):
    a=IndexedBase('a')
    i=Idx('i',dim)

    g=a[0]+x**dim
    for i in range(1,dim):
        g+=x**i*a[i]

    # calculate fg = f o g 
    # and gf = g o f
    fg=f
    gf=g
    fg=expand(f.subs(x,g))
    gf=expand(g.subs(x,f))

    # calculate the difference d=(f o g) - (g o f)
    # and check how to choose the coefficients of g
    # such that it will become 0

    difference=(fg-gf).as_poly(x)
    candidates=solve(difference.all_coeffs()[:dim],[a[i] for i in range(dim)])
    replacements=[(a[i],candidates[0][i]) for i in range(dim)]

    if (difference.subs(replacements)==0):
        return g.subs(replacements)
    else:
        return None
```

Also, you should add [some documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) so others can understand what your function does.

## Related: Removing Global Variables

Managing state can be a pain. Keeping track of what can be in which state can be a headache. It *isn't* of course unmanageable in this case, but it would be useful to get rid of the state. To do so, I would add a [main function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20158605/667648).

```
def main():
    f = x**3 + 3*x
    dim = 5
    g = poly_commute(f, dim)
    if g:
        pprint(g)
    else:
        print("No solution exists.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## PEP 8:

There is some spacing of equations that seem to be off. This is explained in ["Other recommendations" of PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations):

> If operators with different priorities are used, consider adding whitespace around the operators with the lowest priority(ies). Use your own judgment; however, never use more than one space, and always have the same amount of whitespace on both sides of a binary operator:

```
# Correct:
i = i + 1
submitted += 1
x = x*2 - 1
hypot2 = x*x + y*y
c = (a+b) * (a-b)

# Wrong:
i=i+1
submitted +=1
x = x * 2 - 1
hypot2 = x * x + y * y
c = (a + b) * (a - b)
```